# Sitemap issues with dynamic pages

Tags: sitemap

I have created a website and I would like to create a sitemap for Google to crawl it.

The website retreives from a database description of courses bases on course_id with this url format:

```
  http://formationmtl.com/coursedescription.php?course_id=1
  http://formationmtl.com/coursedescription.php?course_id=2
  etc..
```

Now I cannot guaranty that a certain course_id exists as it may be deleted.

I used a 3rd party product online to generate my sitemap and it got me this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
- <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
- <!--  created with Free Online Sitemap Generator www.xml-sitemaps.com 
  --> 
- <url>
  <loc>http://formationmtl.com/</loc> 
  </url>
- <url>
  <loc>http://formationmtl.com/index.php</loc> 
etc...
```

How can I modify this to incorporate my dynamic pages?

This might seams a silly question but I am very new to this.

Thanks,

Comment: Does your database have something like "Course Title" in it? Or just "Course Description"? Because, if it does, then you would make a php sitemap as opposed to an xml sitemap, and do a foreach loop and grab every available course-id and create a sitemap from the results

Comment: mmm interesting... and does google accept a php site map?

Comment: the idea is to make the file sitemap.php, however, when the php runs, it actually outputs a proper xml sitemap (using echo, etc.), so what you are doing is outputting an xml file, just rendered via php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the idea is to make the file sitemap.php, however, when the php runs, it actually outputs a proper xml sitemap (using echo, etc.), so what you are doing is outputting an xml file, just rendered via php.

just make sure that the first line of the xml file is escaped properly, such as:

```
<?php    

  echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>';


  // RUN Database / PHP stuff Here
  // Output properly formatted XML using echo or something to that effect

?>
```

That is the design logic behind creating a php / xml sitemap. You can then submit to Google the link to your sitemap: ie http://www.example.com/sitemap.php

When the google-bot crawls your sitemap, it will run the php, which will output a proper xml sitemap (as long as you didn't forget to escape the first line of the xml).